# What biological changes would have to be made to make a flying human/bird hybrid (harpy)

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design

Obviously you need to do more then add wings to a human. What biological changes would have to be made to  humans in order to make a harpy that could fly ( or at least glide.)

Comment: I can't mark this as a duplicate (new guy), but your question seems to be answered in this WB Question. And I hate paraphrasing/plagiarising, so all credit should go to this guy for answering. http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23145/how-to-make-a-flying-human

Comment: Already asked : http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/36722/anatomically-correct-harpy